# How do I defeat the regenerating enemy close to the Infiltrator boss fight?

Tags: lords-of-the-fallen

In Lords of the Fallen, there is an enemy at a stairway close to the Infiltrator boss fight. He's holding a two-handed weapon and is quite aggressive. As soon as his health bar is depleted, instead of dieing he will punch the ground three or four times and return at full health. Standing close to him during his regeneration will stun me and he takes no damage until his health bar is full again.

What do I have to do to defeat him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoiler:

> When he regenerates,  you'll notice that there is a red line of energy coming off him.  If you follow the line, it will lead you to a jar that contains the heart of that enemy. Break the jar and that particular one will become mortal. I managed to come across this by a complete mistake after running through that entire area, bypassing the buggers.

Comment: Just as a note to add, breaking the vase was not enough. I also had to pick up the item that each vase dropped.